# Filter file names s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have folder below:

```
my-bucket/2021/10/other-nested-dirs
my-bucket/2021/10/info.json
my-bucket/2021/11/other-nested-dirs
my-bucket/2021/11/info.json
```

How can I just get info.json key path

Right now I am doing

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('data-for-seo-adwords-data')
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='2021')
for obj in objs:
    print(obj.key)
    if 'info' in obj.key:
        info_json_files.append(obj.key)
return info_json_files
```

How can I just get info.json file.

Right now I am filtering in all the files etc but is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Butter in what sense? Does you code even work? `info_json_files` is undefined and the code has wrong indentation.

Comment: The filenames need to be filtered in your program, so your code is (generally) correct. I'd use: `if obj.key.endswith('info.json')`

Comment: @Marcin I added the code for referrence only.

Comment: Its difficult to help if this is not real code. If this is real one, what's wrong with it? What errors do you get?